# Cloud init script

Tags: linux, bash, cloud-init

I'm creating a cloud init script which should have following commands:

`- [sudo, curl, -ks, 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg' | sudo, apt-key, add - ]`

However, my Visual Studio Code shows me an red error lines after the pipe. Is is something wrong here? How should syntax be?  As far as I know, yaml can use ":" sign, thus I put the hyperlink in the quotes, what about the latter part of command?

Comment: Partially yes, many thanks. What about echo command?

Comment: Pipe is a shell construct, and when you pass a list of strings it is not executed in a shell. You probably want to make the whole command a string, which causes it to execute in a shell.